# Convert a input string to GET variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create an ajax search page, which shows live results similar to google.

Right now I am struggling with how to convert a search query such as `small dog` to a `GET` parameter, in this case it would be `"searchresults?search=small+dog"`. The thing I want is to replace all white space between words to `+` and to remove whitespaces before and after words.

I think it's possible with regex, or is there some javascript or jquery function to encode that?

I tried using `escape`, `encodeURI`, ... , but it made whitespace `%20`. Will PHP understand that they are multiple words?

Comment: No, it will not. But it's not a problem to split your data string to multiple words via `explode` function in PHP.

Comment: Are you doing a form submission? An AJAX request? A redirect? Where exactly do you need to escape the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually escape a query component in Javascript, simply use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var url = '/searchresults?seach=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

To trim the query string before, use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) on the string.

Probably also useful: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting it in the URL which causes all sorts of escaping issues you should just POST and send data to your search file like this:

**Your AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php'
    ,async: true
    ,cache: false
    ,type: 'POST' // <-- method of sending to server
    ,data: {
               'search': ' small dog '; // notice white space before and after
           }
    ,dataType: 'json' // server returns info in this format
    ,success: function(data){

        // do something here with return data
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**search.php**

```
echo trim($_POST['search']); // gives you 'small dog'
```

Comment: How is that *not* "putting it in the URL"? You're just hiding it behind a jQuery abstraction and an "invisible" AJAX request. It still puts the escaped data into the URL!

Comment: idk, use POST then. I'm not a cop

Comment: You still have the exact same problem using POST, only that the data is moved slightly down inside the HTTP request.

Comment: @deceze it still sends like a URL GET does but unless your server has something wrong with it then it parses properly by the time your script touches it

Comment: Body data in POST requests (colloquially "POST data") and URL query data (colloquially "GET data") are both identically URL encoded. There's no difference to their format. PHP treats them the same way. The only difference is that "GET data" appears in the URL and "POST data" appears in the HTTP request a little further down after the headers. There's a big difference in how GET and POST requests are treated by intermediaries though, so don't substitute a POST for a GET when you don't need it. Here, a GET is certainly what's needed, not a POST.

Comment: How can you tell it's "needed"?

Comment: POST requests are for actively altering data on the server, GET requests are for passive requests. HTTP/REST basics.

Comment: Good luck getting into complex searches where a user might (will eventually) enter a literal % symbol or better yet a literal + symbol.

Comment: Uhm... you'd properly *encode* that using `encodeURIComponent()`. That's exactly its job: encoding characters with a special meaning to escape sequences.

Comment: However there are still length restriction on the get request in some browsers

Answer (score -1):

```
$.get("searchresults", {search : query}, function(data){
  // do something
});
```

it'll add '+' automatically, on the php side, you can simply call [urldecode($str)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php);

Comment: -1 for "jQuery is the answer". It's trivial to do manually what jQuery does for you. You also don't need to urldecode the result on the PHP side if taken from `$_GET`.